# Residency/Citizenship Fast-Tracked Through Investment

Tags: citizenship

I overheard a few people talking about this and state that Singapore and the US fast-tracked citizenship or residency for people who invested in their countries.  Any truth to this ***or*** what countries do this, if any?

Comment: Here in the UK there's an [Investor visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-investor/overview) which if you pay the super premium service (which you'd have money for anyway!) for same day decision! Takes a couple of years to get full status however.

Comment: @MackieeE Wow, this is news to me.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6):

The U.S. does have a program where you can [get a green card through investment](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-through-job/green-card-through-investment).  Depending on what you invest in, the minimum is $500,000 or $1,000,000.  I ski at Jay Peak Vermont in the winter, and that ski resort has used this program to greatly expand its services.  Here is an excerpt from the linked page:

> **Green Card Through Investment**
>
> Entrepreneurs (and their spouses and unmarried children under 21) who
>   make an investment in a commercial enterprise in the United States and
>   who plan to create or preserve ten permanent full time jobs for
>   qualified United States workers, are eligible to apply for a green
>   card (permanent residence).
>
> Up to 10,000 visas may be authorized each fiscal year for eligible
>   entrepreneurs.
>
> You must invest $1,000,000, or at least $500,000 in a targeted
>   employment area (high unemployment or rural area).  In return, USCIS
>   may grant conditional permanent residence to the individual.
>
> For more information, see Section 203(b)(5) of the Immigration and
>   Nationality Act (INA) and 8 CFR 204.6.
>
> **Eligibility Criteria**
>
> You may be eligible to receive permanent residence based on investment
>   if:
>
> - You have an approved Form I-526, Immigrant Petition by Alien Entrepreneur
> - You are admissible to the United States
> - An immigrant visa is immediately available

Comment: An excerpt or summary from the linked page would help make this a good answer. Links, even government ones, go stale, as many of us learned when the IRS had a Mahon web update a few years back.

Comment: Interesting. I guess they figure that if you can afford to invest that much you're a good risk..

Answer (score 1):

Hungary recently introduced a [residency bond program](http://www.residency-bond.eu/index.html), which will allow you for visa free Schengen travels, and a lifetime residency after 5 years. The minimum you have to invest is €300.000, but you get the money back after 5 years, making this a very attractive (and also very controversial) way to get a Schengen visa.

I couldn't find a proper English version of the actual law (which is not surprising, given you can only invest through government approved, but usually offshore companies, which is partly the reason why this option is controversial), but here is an excerpt from the FAQ from [one of these](http://www.residency-bond.eu/FAQ-residency-bond-program.html) middleman companies:

> WHAT IS THE HUNGARIAN RESIDENCY BOND PROGRAM?
>
> The Hungarian Parliament
>   adopted a new regulation regarding 'investor residency' in Hungary.
>   This Program offers permanent residency under preferential conditions
>   for non-EU nationals who have at least EUR 360,000 to invest. Please
>   note that EUR 300,000 will be refunded to you after 5 years.
>
> IS THE RESIDENCY BOND PROGRAM APPROVED BY THE
>   HUNGARIAN GOVERNMENT?
>
> Yes. A law, passed on 11th December 2012 and
>   modified in 2014, offers permanent residency in Hungary for non-EU
>   nationals willing to invest in government residency bonds.
>
> WHAT ARE THE BENEFITS OF THE PROGRAM?
>
> The main advantage is
>   that you and your family become a permanent resident in Hungary, a
>   member country of European Union thus you can move freely within
>   Schengen countries in Europe (Schengen visa).
>
> IS THE PROGRAM POPULAR?
>
> Hungarian Residency Bond Program
>   is getting popular: number of residence permits issued increases
>   enormously. Until now more than 3429 Residency Government Bonds have
>   been purchased. Hungarian authorities hope that the trend will
>   continue in 2016 as well.

The law in Hungarian [can be read here](http://mkogy.jogtar.hu/?page=show&docid=a1200220.TV)